# How to enable to enable live credentials for REST API direct Credit Card Payments

Tags: api, rest, paypal, credentials

I seem to be unable to enable Live credentials to accept direct credit card payments for Paypal REST API. Here is what I do:

1. Log into http://developer.paypal.com
2. Go to application tab and click on my application name
3. In the ACCEPT PAYMENTS section it shows:
   Accept credit cards directly Enabled for test only How to enable live credentials?
   I click on 'How to enable live credentials' link, which further opens up the following:

   > Important Live credentials are disabled for this feature. To enable
   >   direct credit card processing, please provide addition information
   >   about yourself and your business.
   >
   > ```
   > To meet regulatory requirements, we need to collect your business details. This may include:
   > U.S Business owner Social Security Number, date of birth, and other personal details.
   > U.S Business Tax ID (EIN, ITIN) and other business information.
   > ```
   >
   > Get started
4. I click on the 'Get Started' Link and am only taken back to the My APP section of the Application tab.

After step 4 I went to go about trying to find a direct link to how to get the process started and came up with the following:

1. Followed the the following instructions:
   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

While I do now have API Signature Credentials including, API username, API password, and Signature, it still only shows that for "Accept credit cards directly" I am only "Enabled for test only"

I would greatly appreciate any advise or alternative solution to get this fixed.

Thanks!

Sev

Answer (score 4):

If you have US Personal PayPal Account in Live , You will not be able to Direct Credit Card Payments in Live .  This is currently a Limitation. You need to upgrade to Business Account with Mobile Payment Library or Website Payments PRO Account as mentioned below. There is no ALternative available at this time

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

Direct Credit Card Payments
The PayPal REST API supports direct credit card payments, which are credit card payments without a separate web approval flow, in the following countries:

Canada*
United States
United Kingdom*
* Direct credit card payment outside the US requires a Website Payments Pro account (available in the UK and Canada):

Website Payments Pro (UK)
Website Payments Pro (Canada)
In supported countries, the PayPal REST API allows direct credit card payments that use the following currencies:

Currency    Currency Code
United States dollar    USD
Pound sterling  GBP
Canadian dollar CAD
Euro    EUR
Japanese yen    JPY

Comment: I have US paypal account but i still can not access the live credentials for direct credit card processing? Any help?