# Paypal rest api

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have integrated PayPal REST API with PayPal SDK. It's working fine on sandbox when we are using sandbox credentials but when using live PayPal credentials, the save card functionality on PayPal (using REST API) is working fine, but when we try to make payments using the card id of PayPal (generated by PayPal like CARD-8K0630766A878805HYRGHBCD), We are facing an error like;

```
    Exception: Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment. Retried 0 times.
    {
     "name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT",
     "message":"Unauthorized payment",
     "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT",
     "debug_id":"3424fdf3dac86"
   }
```

We have done lot of R&D but could not get the issue.

Please let me know what we are missing or the mistake from our end so that the issue is resolved as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an authorize failed, have  you  ever  enable  your live Credentials  as it's not enabled by default.

Comment: How can we enable the live credentials? We are not able to access "Direct credit cards" as those are not enabled even though we have filled all the genuine information. Please let us know.

Comment: try http://support.powa.com/kb-37 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148139/how-to-enable-to-enable-live-credentials-for-rest-api-direct-credit-card-payment

Comment: I'm  not sure  what went wrong when they verify your information. If It's been a long time since you apply for live Credentials, log in PayPal Resolution Center  to see if there are some issue ready to be done. Or you just email them or call them. By the way,  Your business may falls into a category that is high risk for PayPal, (like selling tickets)...

Comment: Please provide us information rest api not direct payment method Rakesh sharma

Comment: we have not filled up my back account and cardit card in paypal.. We just have create rest api client id and secret key. Is bank account or cardit card require to do this ? Please suggest us Jiang

Comment: Please help us to do this

Comment: I will look into it, (PayPal's document is really in a mass...) I don't  know much details since  our product manager deal with that then, maybe I could ask him for help!

Comment: Yes jiang, please do if you can!

Answer (score 1):

To switch Sandbox to Live, you need to change "mode" from "sandbox" to "live", and use Live client/secret pair. Any object/paypal-entities you have created using sandbox mode will no longer work, you have to re-create them using live credentials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus#enableDCC
2. Make sure Your "Direct credit cards" and "Future Payment" are enabled